# using args in expect module ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to run a command in a specific directory. I am using expect module because I want to pass password after that command is run.

But I am getting below error:

```
  Unsupported parameters for expect module: args
```

I got to know from this error that I can not use args with expect module. But I wanted to know how can I run that command in the specific directory.

```
-name: run a command
 expect: 
    command: "I run my command here"
    response: "{{password}}"
    args:
      chdir: "/tmp/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the `expect` module tells us that there is no `args` argument for the module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html

So you need to specify `chdir` as an argument:

```
- name: run a command
  expect: 
    command: "I run my command here"
    responses: "{{password}}"
    chdir: "/tmp/"
```